# In Redux, Why it checks all reducer for one case to be executed?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I came to know that in react-redux if we dispatch one action so it checks all cases of reducers throughout application. 
In case of big application that should not be the right way.

Is it not time taking process and coz performance get reduced?

Comment: You can move the most frequent used actions to the top of your switch.case statement if you care about performance here. Honestly, I don't. It's `O(n)` and it's not 'millions' of actions that I usually define, usually it's far below 100.

Comment: And - you don't have to use switch/case - it's just the common practise. You could also add a map that maps the actions to the handler methods, if you aim for `O(1)` complexity. But... It's not worth the optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Redux is based on pub-sub model.
So in order for a subscribed reducer to listen for its actions, it needs to go through all the actions.
One solution would be to cache the actions and their store udpates.
Check for example:
[Redux cache middleware](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-cache-middleware)

Comment: Caching solves problems if the execution time of an action is long and the action always return the same data - like a response from an external service. He was more concerned about the switch/case statements in the reducers.